# Function in Postgres

Tags: vb.net, postgresql

```css
Imports Npgsql
Imports System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting

Public Class Form1
    Dim connstring As String = String.Format("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;" +
  "Username=postgres;Password=Maestro;Database=EMS_Demo_db;")
    Dim conn As NpgsqlConnection = New NpgsqlConnection(connstring)
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'Last seven days Consumption
        If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
            CheckBox2.Checked = False
            DataGridView1.Visible = True
            DataGridView2.Visible = False
            DataGridView3.Visible = False
            DataGridView4.Visible = False
            Chart1.Visible = True
            Try
                conn.Open()
                Dim Command As NpgsqlCommand = New NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM lastsevendays_sp ('" + DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "')", conn)
                Dim reader As NpgsqlDataReader = Command.ExecuteReader()
                Dim data_Table1 As New DataTable
                data_Table1.Load(reader)
                DataGridView1.DataSource = data_Table1
                reader.Close()
                conn.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            End Try
```

I am trying to fetch my postgres function in table adapter by developing connection string using ODBC driver.Connection is successfully developed but it only shws table in server explorer and not the stored  procedure [Function].i know by query it is possible but how can i achieve this by using ODBC driver.

Any Help will be appreciated.This is the code i am using to execute function

Comment: Um ... ODBC can run arbitrary SQL queries too.

Comment: but i want to add my function in my dataset so how can i ..?

Comment: With which software are you connecting to PostgreSQL server using ODBC ?

Comment: @Parth show your code written in vb.net

Comment: what you meant by *but it only shws table in server explorer*, this ?

Comment: I am connecting with visual studio